# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send - Only on Windows server 2016

Tags: c#, webclient

Has the following code.

```
      using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

                    byte[] data = client.DownloadData(resource.MainPictureUrl);

                    if (media.BinaryData == null)
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(resource.MainPictureUrl);

                        media.BinaryData = BlobFactory.Service.CreateBlob(media.BinaryDataContainer, $".{extension}");
                    }
                    media.BinaryData.WriteAllBytes(data);
                }
```

It downloads an image, this works well in local environment, but when I deploy to the server. Windows Server 2016 and IIS I get the following error message.

Have scanned the internet and everyone talks about this line: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls`

However, this does not seem to help.

Some tips, why is it specific to the server.

Run ASP.NET version: .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319

**EDIT**

Specifies the url for the image in IE. Receives the error message:
This page should be displayed

Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https: // site-uri again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure

Any setting on the server that blocks this?

But if I check the page from my Win 10 machine, I see this:

This page is secure (valid HTTPS).
Certificate - valid and trusted
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA.
View certificate
Connection - secure connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_256_GCM.
Resources - all served securely
All resources on this page are served securely.

**EDIT 2 - Problem solved**

The problem is solved,

The error was that the server was locked via proxy not being allowed to make calls to the Internet, this was solved by whitelisting the domain images downloaded from.

So both code and ASP.NET versions have been correct all the time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this happens because you are using .Net 4.0. In .NET 4.0 default transport level security standard is TLS 1.1. The solution for your problem is to upgrade application to the latest .NET framework. In 4.6.1 for instance, TLS 1.2 is a default cryptographic standard.

Its working on your local, because you may have .net 4.5 installed on your system.
You can try doing this:

```
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

instead of

```
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

and it will work.

Here is a general guideline:

1. **.NET 4.6**: and above: TLS 1.2 is supported by default.
2. **.NET 4.5**: TLS 1.2 is supported, but it’s not a default protocol.
3. **.NET 4.0**. TLS 1.2 is not supported, but if you have .NET 4.5 (or above) installed on the system then you still can opt in for TLS 1.2
   even if your application framework doesn’t support it.
4. **.NET 3.5 or below**. TLS 1.2 is not supported (*) and there is no workaround. Upgrade your application to more recent version of the framework.

Reference: https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: In Visual Studio the target Framework is set to: .NET Framework 4.6.1. 

Do I need to upgrade the .NET version on the server? Because that's where it doesn't work. But via Visual studio it works.

Comment: try changing it to: SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls and check if it works on your server

Comment: yes, upgrade the .net framework on server or change your code

Comment: The server already seems to be running on version 4.6.1

Cannot install that version anyway, get a message that this version or better is already installed.

Comment: Created an api endpoint, to check the version on the server.

Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Same error with: `SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls`